# React Native - make view in FlatList ignore scroll events but accept onPress events

Tags: react-native, event-handling

I'm creating a react native app that displays a list of posts in a FlatList. The posts are either text or images. I have 2 requirements that I'm struggling to achieve:

- Scrolling: I want the user to be able to scroll the list of posts effortlessly i.e., the posts should ignore scroll events so they get handled by the parent FlatList.
- Select/Click: I want the user to be able to select text or click on links in the posts i.e., the posts should handle onPress() events.

If I render the posts as normal Views in a FlatList, text selection and clicking works as expected but scrolling works poorly. This is because the posts sometimes capture the scroll events. The behavior is much worse with posts that include large images. I can fix the scrolling problem by adding `pointerEvents="none"` to the posts. However, in this case, it will no longer be possible to select text in the posts or click on any links.

Is there a way to achieve smooth scrolling while still being able to select text and click on links in each individual post? I tested this on Android only.

Answer (score 0):

To disable scrolling you can use the prop **scrollEnabled={false}** , this is considering the Flatlist inherets Scrollview props as is explained in the [react docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

To make clickable a text, use some [touchable](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html), TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, TouchableNativeFeedback.